# How to PREVENT NavigationLink form pushing view on stack based on a boolean

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a user-signup NavigationView where they enter their account info in separate views in a NavigationView stack.

After they enter in a email/username I check the email is available on the backend and return a boolean if it is available.

I want to prevent the next view from pushing onto the stack based on this boolean and display an error message (I have the error message working) but I don't know how?

Is there a NavigationLink modifier I could use for this or another way?

See images for reference

```
class SignupNavigationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var signupErrorMessage = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var reconfirmPassword = ""

    func checkEmailAvailability(email: String, completion: @escaping
 (Result<EmailAvailability, Error>) -> Void) {
        AuthService.checkEmailAvailability(email: email, completion: 
completion)
    }
}
```

```
struct SignupEmailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
       
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                    Text(signupNavigationViewModel.signupErrorMessage)
                    HStack {
                        TextField("enter e-mail", text: 
$signupNavigationViewModel.email )
                    }
                NavigationLink("continue", destination: NavigationLink("continue", destination: 
SignupUsername(signupNavigationViewModel: signupNavigationViewModel))
                    .disabled(signupNavigationViewModel.email.isEmpty)
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        checkIfEmailIsAvailable()
           // if email is available allow next view to be pushed on stack        
                    })
            }
        }
```

```
struct SignupUsername: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel : SignupNavigationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(signupNavigationViewModel.signupErrorMessage)
                TextField("Enter a username", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.username )
                NavigationLink("continue", destination: 
SignupPasswordView(signupNavigationViewModel: signupNavigationViewModel) )
                    .disabled(signupNavigationViewModel.username.isEmpty)
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                         {check username formatting}
       {check if available, if avail allow password input view }
                    })
            }
 }
```

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry about that @pawello2222, I added the code. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use NavigationLink indirectly via programmatic activation when condition met, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64493903/12299030.